# Scale on hover effect for a 'next-link' which contains a social platform .svg file

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

The code:

```
import InstagramIcon from './assets/IG.svg';

export const Footer = ({ footer }: FooterInterface) => {
return (
.....
  <Link href={`${footer?.instagram_link}`}>
    <a>
      <InstagramIcon />
    </a>
  </Link>
)}
```

This is what I want to obtain:
[image]

The Instagram icon should scale up on hover.

Comment: Please add the css code for the shown components you have so far so we can have a look and help to integrate the hover.

Comment: No css code, I am using tailwindcss 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right class

```
<a className="transition duration-500 transform hover:scale-125">
```

'transform' class needs to be added, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Link href={`${footer?.instagram_link}`} >
              <a className="hover:scale-150">
                <InstagramIcon />
              </a>
            </Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states and https://tailwindcss.com/docs/scale you would want to add `hover:scale-150` as a class to your A-Tag (you can use other scale sizes like `scale-110` or `scale-120` too):

```
import InstagramIcon from './assets/IG.svg';

export const Footer = ({ footer }: FooterInterface) => {
return (
.....
  <Link href={`${footer?.instagram_link}`}>
    <a className="hover:scale-150">
      <InstagramIcon />
    </a>
  </Link>
)}
```

Comment: It's weird, something like: hover:bg-red-700 it's working, it turns the button to red, but scale doesn't work...

Comment: Are you including scale in your tailwind.config.js as stated in https://tailwindcss.com/docs/scale ?

Comment: it looks like this: variants: {
    extend: {
      scale: ['group-hover'],
    },
  },

Comment: Does using `scale-150` without the `hover:` modifier work? Looking at your configuration it should work as `By default, only responsive, hover and focus variants are generated for scale utilities.` Youre adding `group-hover` too so basic `hover:scale` should work.

Comment: Does using scale-150 without the hover: modifier work? - It doesn't, it should be a problem because is a 'svg-icon'?

Comment: Youre putting the `hover:scale-150` on the link, not the icon itself, right?

Comment: yes, on the <a> tag, something like hover:bg-purple-700 it works, turns the icon into purple

Comment: So to seal this discussion and keep things on-topic: The solution to your question is contained in my answer. The fact the `hover:scale-150` tailwindcss class doesnt work in your project is not related to this particular question. I suggest you isolate that problem to a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example including your tailwind config etc and open up another question with that.

Comment: will do. Thank you!